# Ways to host a web server with ports bellow 1024 blocked (except 22)?

Tags: proxy, port, nat, tunneling

My provider is Ask4 and they only provide 1:1 NAT which opens ports 22 and all above 1024. No UPnP. However, I want to use ports 80 and 443 for a web server.

Is there a way without changing those ports to host a web server?

Can SSH Dynamic port forwarding or Proxies/Tunnelling software help me with this?

I want to avoid VPNs as they tend to be a slower solution. The more responsive the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, i looked into it further and after a couple of days found that a reverse proxy was the best.

It works by running on one server running apache, nginx, etc and then basically sending that traffic to the designated IP. You can also select a port!